# how to publish in visual studio code to IIS server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-code

i'm starting to learning Angular 2 in visual studio code. When i'm searching about a way to publish my web project, everywhere I search is using GitHub and Azure. Is there no way to publish it to local IIS server??

Comment: I run code using node but also test the same project in visual studio which runs it under IIS Express. A colleague also has his VS setup to use IIS. Create a folder and drop the project inside.

Comment: Been trying with this VS-Code extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-deploy but no luck at all with web-deploy. Poor docs and cryptic information.

Answer (score 1):

-Build your Angular2 app using ng build --prod --aot

-Copy contents of the dist directory, to the root of your ASP.NET project. if you don't have create an empty project in VS 2017 (Or any version of the big VS)

-Use web deployment in VS 2017

Note: If you are finding a hard time loading html resources, then check base url tag in index.html
Hope it helps